# How to delete a record from database using Entity WebApi

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to delete a row from my database using Entity Framework in my WebApi Project, but everytime i tried to delete i succeeded but the ID still count!
Ex : Let's say i have 5 rows and i delete all of 5 rows,if i make a POST,it will be count on 6,7,8... I want to use the concept of stack if i erase the first row of 5 the second row must to be the first...

My simple SQL SERVER script:

```
create table Usuário
(
Id int not null identity,
Name varchar(200) not null,
Email varchar(200) not null,
Telefone varchar(200) not null
Constraint Pk_Client Primary Key(Id)
)
```

API Method:

```
[Route("delete")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Usuario usuario = data.Usuario.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
            data.Usuario.Remove(usuario);
            data.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Sucesso");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: You mean the ID column shouldn't be an Identity column?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this stack concept which you've mentioned? Would a timestamp column for when the record was created be a more robust way to implement the required behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the value for "Id" field because it is an "identity"-field and will been set automatically. If you want to reset the counter, you must truncate the Table.

Each insert in the Table will increment the Value of "Id" by one.

You can also deactivate the auto-field and set it manually, but here you should get the last inserted id for each query.

I hope, I have understood your question correctry.